# ODBC SQLDriverConnect crashes when running as a service

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, odbc

The software is written in C.
It can run as an application (sdm -debug) or as a service (net start sdm).
I issue both commands from an administrator command line.
When running as an application all is well.
When running as a service the software crashes when calling SQLDriverConnect.

The Windows application log file contains the following:
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9659_none_d08cfd96442b25cc\MSVCR80.dll

I am running on Windows 10.
Not sure why the software is using such DLL.
Have tried changing the name of the DLL in the specified to observer changes but the path seems to be protected.

I have created a post in my blog with considerable additional information. Please use the following link:

{https://www.johncanessa.com/2020/02/29/odbc-sqldriverconnect-crashes-additional-info/}?

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more information here. You are asking for help debugging and application without providing any details at all.

Answer (score 0):

look at this 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9f2357f-46c4-4da9-9346-66b1d406aa00/faulting-module-path-cwindowssystem32msvcr120dll?forum=w7itproappcompat
if its something in your code - you need to provide it here.
if its something environmental (like the c++ redist as mentioned here) - try different version or use the proposed solution

Comment: Tried all the suggestions from the link on two Windows 10 machines. The issue persists. The 32-bit software runs as an app in the console with or without administrator privileges. It fails when running as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly caused the issue but it happened after receiving a Windows Update. The solution was to use Non Sucking Service Manager (NSSM) utility to install and remove the software to run as a service.